# SQL Server Billing Implementation - The Current Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, payment, billing

The current system I'm assigned to has no record of customer purchases, deposits, and rewarded credits (by administrators) - just a Credit column in the Users table. Every time a user deposits money, that column is incremented. If they buy something on the website, their credit gets deducted.

The full billing implementation details are not that important right now, but I know that we somehow have to tally up purchases and deposits to arrive at the current balance.

Every time we want to know a customer's balance, I figure we would have to run a stored procedure to tally up every payment/deposit record since the customer's very first transaction, right? If so, then that seems like a pretty heavy request especially if queried often.

There could be some "balanced approach" where we could store the balance as we currently do, and routinely (via scheduling, I guess), recalculate each user's balance with the stored procedure mentioned above.

I want to know what the best practices are for managing user's balance. I'm shooting for both consistent/correct data and efficiency if that's even possible in this scenario. What do you advise?

What resources are there about implementing billing systems?

Answer (score 2):

Why not store the current balance, and the list of transactions?

When a transaction occurs, write a row to the transaction history table, and also update the customer balance column.

If you need the customer balance, look in the customer table, if you need the transaction history then look in the transaction history table.

You can guarantee consistency by wrapping the two database writes (transaction & customer) in an atomic transaction.

Comment: Seems like a "duh" on my part, yet answers to several similar questions on this forum never suggested this. Thank you.